# Swiss projection coordinates to ellipsoidal coordinates

Tags: c#, wgs84

I am trying to convert CH1903+ coordinates into WGS84 coordinates based on the following example provided by the swiss "Bundesamt für Statistik" using C#.

Example:

[image: Example]

As far i can calculate all values like shown in the example. But in the end when i try to calculate the variable "S" based on the values in the example i am getting wrong results.

```
double E = 2679520.05; 
double alpha = 1.00072913843038; 
double phi = 0.820535226; 
double b = 0.820535226;
double K = 0.0030667323772751
```

I tried both implementations:

```
double S = Math.Log(Math.Tan(Math.PI / 4.0 + phi / 2.0)); --> result: 0.931969600979248
```

or

```
double S = 1/alpha * (Math.Log(Math.PI/4 + b/2) - K) + E * Math.Log(Math.Tan((Math.PI/4) + (Math.Asin(E * Math.Sin(phi))/2.0))); --> result: NaN
```

Can somebody tell what's wrong in my implementation that i am getting this wrong results? If i understand the example correctly both calculations should return 0.933114264192610 as result for the given values.

Comment: BTW here is the link to the full documentation https://www.swisstopo.admin.ch/content/swisstopo-internet/en/online/calculation-services/_jcr_content/contentPar/tabs/items/documents_publicatio/tabPar/downloadlist/downloadItems/20_1467104436749.download/refsys_e.pdf

Comment: Use a spatial library and tell it which ellipsoid to use. Don't try to hard-code it.  Such libraries are thorougly tested to ensure minimal errors. Databases with spatial features can already do such conversions, eg SQL Server.

Comment: EF Core 2.2 added spatial support by including the open source [NetTopologySuite](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite) package. [This question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165022/how-do-i-transform-a-point-using-nettopologysuite) from gis.stackexchange.com points to a standalone NTS package just for coordinate conversions, `ProjNET4GeoAPI `

Comment: Thx for the feedback but i like to know what's the problem here (especially in the C# implementation) and i don't want to add a new package when i can solve it in a few lines of code. I dont think that there is a solution for this specific problem in "ProjNET4GeoAPI". At least i didn't found a documentation for this package.

Comment: in this case you need to post input coordinates and expected outputs *coordinates*. You should test the transformation using other systems before trying to code your one. That's what I intend to do to find what the results should look like before trying to see what's wrong with the calculation. It could be just that you are using `double` resulting in rounding errors. Spatial libraries take care to correct for such errors.

Comment: i posted all required parameters to reproduce this problem. the 5 variables (E, alpha, phi, b, K) listed in my question are all parameters u need feed the functions. The input coordinates (swiss coordinate system are listed in the linked example N = 1212273.44 and E = 2679520.05). Behind each function i posted which results i am getting based on the 5 parameters and in the linked example you can see which results are the correct ones. The 5 parameters are calculated by myself and they are correct because in the example link they got the same results.

Comment: So only the 2 functions i posted (which should be equivalent like described in the example) are getting wrong results. So for me there is a problem in my C# implementation. The expected result is 0.933114264192610 and my result is 0.931969600979248. So it looks like there is a rounding problem but in the first function i am not doing any roundings and this is what i dont understand.

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation for converting swiss CH1903+ coordinates -> decimal coordinates (WGS84) which works good so far

Example CH1903+ Coordinates N = 1249251.544, E = 2645320.487;

```
// swiss CH1903+ coordinates
double N = 1249251.544,
       E = 2645320.487;

const double K = 0.0030667323772751; // Konstante der Breitenformel

const double BESSEL_GH = 6377397.155; // grosse Halbachse des Bessel-Ellipsoids 
const double BESSEL_SH = 6356078.963; // kleine Halbachse des Bessel-Ellipsoids 
double GRS_GH = 6.378137 * Math.Pow(10, 6); // grosse Halbachse des GRS84-Ellipsoids 
double GRS_SH = 6.356752314 * Math.Pow(10, 6); ; // kleine Halbachse des GRS84-Ellipsoids 

double E2_BESSEL = (Math.Pow(BESSEL_GH, 2) - Math.Pow(BESSEL_SH, 2)) / Math.Pow(BESSEL_GH, 2), // 1.numerische Exzentrizität (im Quadrat) des Bessel-Ellipsoids 
       E_BESSEL = Math.Sqrt(E2_BESSEL), // 1.numerische Exzentrizität des Bessel-Ellipsoids
       E2_GRS = (Math.Pow(GRS_GH, 2) - Math.Pow(GRS_SH, 2)) / Math.Pow(GRS_GH, 2); // 1.numerische Exzentrizität (im Quadrat) des GRS84-Ellipsoids 

const double TOLERANCE = 0.0000000000000001;

///// swiss coordinates -> ellipsoid coordinates /////
double
    Y = E - 2600000.0, // swiss CH1903 coordinates
    X = N - 1200000.0, // swiss CH1903 coordinates

    PHI_NULL = (46 + 57 / 60.0 + 8.66 / 3600.0) * Math.PI / 180, // geogr. Breite des Nullpunkts in Bern
    LAMBDA_NULL = (7 + 26 / 60.0 + 22.5 / 3600.0) * Math.PI / 180, // geogr. Länge des Nullpunkts in Bern

    R = (BESSEL_GH * Math.Sqrt(1 - E2_BESSEL)) / (1 - E2_BESSEL * Math.Pow(Math.Sin(PHI_NULL), 2)), // Radius der Projektionskugel
    ALPHA = Math.Sqrt(1 + E2_BESSEL / (1 - E2_BESSEL) * Math.Pow(Math.Cos(PHI_NULL), 4)), // Verhältnis Kugellänge zu Ellipsoidlänge

    B_GLOBAL_NULL = Math.Asin(Math.Sin(PHI_NULL) / ALPHA), // Breite des Nullpunkts auf der Kugel

    L_PSEUDO = Y / R, // Kugelkoordinaten bezüglich Pseudoäquatorsystem in Bern
    B_PSEUDO = 2 * (Math.Atan(Math.Pow(Math.E, (X / R))) - (Math.PI / 4)), // Kugelkoordinaten bezüglich Pseudoäquatorsystem in Bern

    L = Math.Atan(Math.Sin(L_PSEUDO) / (Math.Cos(B_GLOBAL_NULL) * Math.Cos(L_PSEUDO) - Math.Sin(B_GLOBAL_NULL) * Math.Tan(B_PSEUDO))), // Kugelkoordinaten bezüglich Nullpunkt Bern 
    B = Math.Asin(Math.Cos(B_GLOBAL_NULL) * Math.Sin(B_PSEUDO) + Math.Sin(B_GLOBAL_NULL) * Math.Cos(B_PSEUDO) * Math.Cos(L_PSEUDO)), // Kugelkoordinaten bezüglich Nullpunkt Bern 

    LAMBDA = LAMBDA_NULL + L / ALPHA,
    PHI = B,
    S = (Math.Log(Math.Tan(Math.PI / 4.0 + B / 2.0)) - K) / ALPHA + E_BESSEL * Math.Log(Math.Tan(Math.PI / 4.0 + Math.Asin(E_BESSEL * Math.Sin(PHI)) / 2.0));

bool cont = true;

// iterate to tolerance
while (cont)
{
    double PHI_TMP = 2 * Math.Atan(Math.Pow(Math.E, S)) - Math.PI / 2;
    double S_TMP = (Math.Log(Math.Tan(Math.PI / 4 + B / 2)) - K) / ALPHA + E_BESSEL * Math.Log(Math.Tan(Math.PI / 4 + Math.Asin(E_BESSEL * Math.Sin(PHI_TMP)) / 2));

    if (Math.Abs(PHI - PHI_TMP) < TOLERANCE)
    {
        cont = false;
    }
    else
    {
        PHI = PHI_TMP;
        S = S_TMP;
    }
}

///// ellipsoid coordinates (CH1903) -> karth. coordinates (CH1903) /////
double RN_CH1903 = BESSEL_GH / (Math.Sqrt(1 - E2_BESSEL * Math.Pow(Math.Sin(PHI), 2))), // Normalkrümmungsradius
       X_KARTH = RN_CH1903 * Math.Cos(PHI) * Math.Cos(LAMBDA),
       Y_KARTH = RN_CH1903 * Math.Cos(PHI) * Math.Sin(LAMBDA),
       Z_KARTH = (RN_CH1903 * (1 - E2_BESSEL)) * Math.Sin(PHI);

///// karth. coordinates (CH1903) -> karth. coordinates (ETRS89/CHTRS95) /////
double X_CH1930P = X_KARTH + 674.374,
       Y_CH1930P = Y_KARTH + 15.056,
       Z_CH1930P = Z_KARTH + 405.346;

///// karth. coordinates (ETRS89/CHTRS95) -> ellipsoid coordinates (ETRS89/CHTRS95) /////
double PHI_ETRS = Math.Atan(Z_CH1930P / Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(X_CH1930P, 2) + Math.Pow(Y_CH1930P, 2))),
       RN_ETRS = BESSEL_GH / (Math.Sqrt(1 - E2_GRS * Math.Pow(Math.Sin(PHI_ETRS), 2)));

cont = true;

// iterate to tolerance
while (cont)
{
    double PHI_ETRS_TMP = Math.Atan((Z_CH1930P / (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(X_CH1930P, 2) + Math.Pow(Y_CH1930P, 2)))) / (1 - (RN_ETRS * E2_GRS) / (RN_ETRS + 0))),
           RN_ETRS_TMP = BESSEL_GH / (Math.Sqrt(1 - E2_GRS * Math.Pow(Math.Sin(PHI_ETRS_TMP), 2)));

    if (Math.Abs(PHI_ETRS - PHI_ETRS_TMP) < TOLERANCE)
    {
        cont = false;
    }
    else
    {
        PHI_ETRS = PHI_ETRS_TMP;
        RN_ETRS = RN_ETRS_TMP;
    }
}

double LAMBDA_ETRS = Math.Atan(Y_CH1930P / X_CH1930P);

///// ellipsoid coordinates (ETRS89/CHTRS95) -> decimal coordinates (WGS84) /////
double lat = PHI_ETRS * 180 / Math.PI;
double lon = LAMBDA_ETRS * 180 / Math.PI;
```